# Any idea what function or logic can be used to achieve this output?

Tags: teradata

Question:

Table A has one column with 4 values

```
col 1
-----
1
2
5
8
```

Output

```
col 1  col 2
-----  -----
    1      2
    2     10
    5     40
    8      8
```

Output should be the existing column with a derived column that is a  cumulative product. When there are no more values to multiply with, the row value should be displayed as is. Cumulative sum can be calculated easily. Any idea how multiplication can be achieved?
I tried using OLAP functions, but no luck.

Comment: How is the order of calculation defined?

Comment: Order by the existing column in the table

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is the product of the current and the next row:

```
col1 * lead(col1,1,1) over (order by col1)
```